# OpenGL ES shader for drawing video frames

Tags: c++, opengl-es, shader, vertex-shader

I'm writing the code that YUV formatted video frame with OpenGL ES.

A video frame decoder library returns has a larger size compares with an original size becuause it has a stride.

Therefore, When a frame is converted into RGB, it will become like this image and a green frame is drawn at the corner of the texture.

[image: RGB video frame]

My current vertex sharder is this. Please teach me how to draw a texture cleanly.

```
void main() { 
  vec3 yuv = get_yuv(nUV) - vec3(0.0625, 0.5, 0.5);
  yuv *= mat3(
  1.16438356, 0.0, 1.59602679,
  1.16438356, -0.391762290, -0.812967647,
  1.16438356, 2.01723214, 0.0);
  gl_FragColor.rgb = yuv;
  gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to OpenGL ES so i don't know much, but maybe this might help.
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/